# Golang stucked until I press CTRL+C (Windows 10)

Tags: go, httphandler

I've got a server-like program in Windows 10 where the main program waits for the requests with http.Handle(dst, handlerStruct), and for every query does the corresponding operations and returns a result or just prints something through the screen.

It usually works fine, but sometimes, and just sometimes, when I leave the program running "waiting" for requests to come in for a long time (3 minutes up) and then I send a request, it just gets "stucked" until I press CTRL+C, and then it returns the values inmediately. So it looks like the program runs well, but the returning thread is having a break or something when I leave it a long time without requests.

This happens ever since I started developing the program, and not only when using functions with goroutines.

For me it looks like it has more to do with Windows 10 than with Golang itself, but it's just very annoying, and of course I don't want this to happen with my server...

Hope you can see what's going wrong here...

Thanks.

---

EDIT

This is the main program waiting for the requests:

```
func main() {

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(10000000)

    http.Handle("/sameDayCombinations", CBR.SameDayCombinationsHandler{})
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Now this is the code of ServeHTTP for the handler:

```
func (h SameDayCombinationsHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    t1 := time.Now()

    q := common.DecodeRequest(r)
    json := common.EncodeAnswer((&h).RetrieveSpecificSolutions(q.Year, q.Month, q.Day, q.DepID, q.ArrID, q.Adults, q.Children, q.Infants), true)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, json)

    t2 := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t2.Sub(t1))
}
```

---

EDIT2

Here I add the stack of a program execution after the appearance of this weird behavior. So, after doing CTRL+C I got this; looks pretty normal to me.

http://pastebin.com/DduvtNZr

Though, now, by empirical demonstration, I'm sure it has to do with the console Prints (probably large prints?). That's a good new, cause it'll only happen while debugging, but stills a weird behavior...

Comment: You should include a minimal example that would reproduce the problem. I use Go on Windows 10 and didn't find anything special about how Go or any other language works on it. I could understand if it happend after days of uptime but 3 minutes is just too little to do anything

Comment: Please show the code in question. A full stack trace from the application would be very useful as well (use `GOTRACEBACK=all` if you generate the stack via a panic)

Comment: Edited. I call GOMAXPROCS just to make sure it uses all that's available.

Comment: There is no need to start 10000000 OS threads. Please set GOMAXPROCS to a reasonable value or use the default which is equal to the number of cores on the machine.

Comment: @jcasado94, but it actually will not use anything. `GOMAXPROCS` is not allocating anything, it's more like an upper bound. Go will allocate threads as it needs them. If it only needs 1 thread then that's what it will allocate even if your `GOMAXPROCS` is 10000000

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem with this https://play.golang.org/p/YCrvKYFVTV Let it run for about 10 minutes before sending a request, didn't even touch the PC the whole time.

Comment: What you've shown here isn't the problem, but we have no idea what is behind the `common.*` calls. A stacktrace showing where things are blocks will help.

Comment: It's hard to catch the problem, so please understand if I'm slow with posting the stacktrace. Thanks.

Comment: I just realised it's not a problem only from the named binary. I am running a random query generator for my server, and it got stucked the same way. It's not doing complicated stuff, just creating queries and printing the responses. Looking at the behavior it had, it could've got stucked before the CTRL+C either at a `body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)` or at a `fmt.Println(string(body))`...

Comment: Added the stack trace. Sorry for the delay, been busy these days.